# Trouble getting ASP Classic global.asa file to run under IIS 7.5

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7.5

I'm trying to troubleshoot an ASP application on my windows 7 computer running IIS 7.5.

The ASP classic application has a bunch of stuff that's configured in a global.asa file, but it doesn't seem to be processed at all on IIS 7.5.

For example this:

```
<OBJECT RUNAT=Server SCOPE=Session ID=ums_dict PROGID="Scripting.Dictionary">
</OBJECT>
```

On the server creates a dictionary object called ums_dict which is unavailable on my PC. There is also a Sub Session_OnStart which does not run.

I've made it its own application and ensured it's in the root of the app, I've also set the app pool to the Classic .NET AppPool, tried both the 2.0 framework and the 4.0 framework, and 32 bit vs 64 bit app pool. I've also made sure the app pool is in classic mode.

Is there ANYTHING else I can try?

Comment: Can you run any classic asp page? If you are using the built-in IIS7.5 from windows 7 make sure the classic asp module is enabled by going to Control Panel > Programs and Features > Windows Features  > Application Development Features and check the ASP node.

Comment: did  you tried the ***checklist*** by @ScotterMonkey ?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a checklist I built when I was moving all my sites from IIS 6 to IIS 7.x:

(1) Do not name site folders with .com at the end.

(2) Create user account:
- [app pool user identity] is app_pool_blahblahblah, pw: xxxxxx

(3) In Server Manager, right click "Web Server (IIS)" and choose "Add Role Services". Add IIS 6 Management Compatibility.

(4) In Server Manager under features add SMTP server.
Install IIS6 Resource Kit so you can 
Use Metabase Explorer.
Grant the [app pool user identity] user read access to the /Local Machine/SmtpSvc/ and /Local Machine/SmtpSvc/1/ nodes in the IIS Metabas

(5) In Application Pool, advanced settings:
- set .Net Framework version to "v2.0" <-- fixed issue with default asp doc not working!
- set "Enable 32-bit applications" to TRUE.
- set managed pipeline mode to "Classic".
- under Process Model, change Identity to "[app pool user identity]" account we created.
- be sure "load user profile" is set to FALSE.
- be sure "maximum worker processes" is "1".

(6) Mail: In IIS 6 Management Console:
http://intellitect.com/configuring-windows-smtp-server-on-windows-2008-for-relay/
- Under SMTP Virtual Server Properties:
    -- "Access" Tab --> Relay: add IPs of this box, including 127.0.0.1
    -- "Delivery" Tab --> Advanced: for "fully qualified domain name" put name of box
    -- "Delivery" Tab --> Advanced: for "smart host" put "dedrelay.secureserver.net"
    -- "Delivery" Tab --> Outbound connections: Make sure limits are set to 100.
    -- "Security" Tab --> add "[app pool user identity]" and IIS_IUSRS

(7) In IIS 7.5 under web site:
- Under ASP:
    -- ONLY IF PROBLEM: set enable buffering to "false"
    -- under limits change max req entity and buffering limit to 1024000000
    -- set script language to "vbscript"
    -- set "send errors to browser" to true
- Authentication --> edit "Anonymous Authentication" and set to app pool identity.
- ONLY IF PROBLEM: under error pages: under 404 set to "/home.asp" and "execute URL"
- ONLY IF PROBLEM: edit c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config: change  to "Allow"
- under Management (at bottom) go into "Configuration Editor".
    -- In the dropdown go to System.web --> http runtime and change maxRequestLength to 1024000000
    -- In the dropdown go to System.webserver/security/requestFiltering --> chg allowDoubleEscaping=true

(8) 
Set "Modify" Permissions for the following folders: 
- windows\temp
- inetpub\temp
- inetpub\mailroot
- ONLY IF PROBLEM: windows\serviceprofiles\networkservice\AppData\Local\Temp?

AND Set Permissions in registry:
- ONLY IF PROBLEM: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines?

FOR THESE USER ACCOUNTS:
- IIS_IUSRS
- [app pool user identity]
- NETWORK SERVICE

(9) Install and Use Process Monitor to find permissions issues - filter